# Chrome (Desktop) touch emulation not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, touch, google-chrome-devtools, emulation

I wrote a little javascript and tried debugging it on latest stable Chrome for Windows 10 (as of writing v48)..

The script works perfectly with mouse-input but as soon as I emulate a mobile/touchdevice with touch emulation on - it's not working and the appropriate console.logs tell me that no touch was detected...

```
function hasTouch() {
        return 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement;
}
var event_start = hasTouch() ? 'touchstart' : 'mousedown',
    event_move = hasTouch() ? 'touchmove' : 'mousemove',
    event_end = hasTouch() ? 'touchend' : 'mouseup';
console.log(event_start + "|" + event_move + "|" + event_end);
```

Firefox with touch emulation on works perfectly! Also physical touch devices work perfectly..

https://jsfiddle.net/j8kLz6wm/1/

So what is wrong with Chrome?

Comment: Your check in hasTouch function is always false in Chrome 48. Why do you need to check it? Could you listen both events all the time?

Comment: I know it is always false - even if you set Touch Emulation to true... that's what I'm asking: WHY is it always false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rewrite your `hasTouch` function like this:

```
function hasTouch() {
  return 'ontouchstart' in window;
}
```